# TokenMismatch error when run codeception test

Tags: laravel-5, codeception

I am getting this error in my log file when I run codeception test case. How to fix this?

**Code:**

```
 public function testUpdatePhone(FunctionalTester $I)
 {
        $I->wantTo('Test update phone');
        $I->sendPUT('/admin/phone/100', [
            'label' => 'My new label'
        ]);
        $I->see('Phone Number updated successfully.');
 }
```

**Command:**

> ./vendor/bin/codecept run
>   tests/functional/AdminPhoneTestCest.php:testUpdatePhone

**Error in Log file:**

> [2015-06-06 05:34:02] local.ERROR: exception
>   'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in
>   /var/www/xxxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:46

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The issue is that the data which is being passed to that test route does not include a valid Laravel csfr_token() stored in a `_token` form field which the middleware in your error is expecting. This field has to be generated for each request, or it will fail authentication. You'll want to search for a work around.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed by adding middleware method as follows

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
 if ($request->header('user-agent') == 'Symfony2 BrowserKit') {
  return $next($request);
 }

 throw new TokenMismatchException;
}
```

Reference: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/latest-v5-laravelframework-csrfmiddleware-changes-broke-codeception-functional-tests

Comment: This is a really dangerous method. Any browser with that agent can bypass the csrf.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using phantomjs, you will need to ensure you have `clear_cookies: true` in your settings as the normal `restart: true` doesn't seem to be supported for phantomjs, so it uses the same token which is invalid in subsequent tests.